# 3D development - Javascript/HTML5/CSS3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, 3d

I am working on this new project, wich is a new technology for me...
I'm working with Appcelerator Titanium, building this 3d application...

My applications suppose to be something like 3d Canvas...
I mean a ability to add objects to canvas (drag&drop),rotate them (3d),
and most important to rotate the whole Canvas(3d).

From checking the subject came with a lot of Plug-Ins and libraries:

Three.js,WebGl,HTML5 Canvas,CSS3...

The question is-Is anybody have an idea what is the best to use for
this mission?

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on your specific needs. If your objects standard elements like text, forms, squares use CSS3. If your elements are 3d primitives such as cubes, cylinders, spheres, use three.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three.js makes it super-easy to make primitives and load pre-generated objects (typically from JSON data).

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/

Check out the examples at the bottom of the page, and note how little code is necessary to do anything. The only disadvantage is the overhead of a huge library like Three.js, along with the fact that it is still in its infancy and changing slightly by the month. Beyond that, there's not much advice I can give you as I have no idea what kinds of objects you plan to put in this canvas or what the goal if the project is.